# find_package does find and at the same time does not find opencvconfig, opencv_dir path set to directory of that file

Tags: cmake

I have some really strange behavior with cmake and opencv.
If cmake has to move 2 directories up, the find_package module no longer finds config file for opencv but also does.
As soon as I move the cmakelists one directory up and change the dir accordingly, the config file is found?

```
set( OpenCV_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4/)
message( ${OpenCV_DIR} )
execute_process(COMMAND ls ${OpenCV_DIR})

find_package(OpenCV 4.2 REQUIRED)

if ( OpenCV_FOUND )
    target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
else()
    message( FATAL_ERROR "Required OpenCV packages not found." )
endif()
```

a section of the terminal dump:

```
Application/GameManagement/test/../../lib/opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4/
OpenCVConfig.cmake
OpenCVConfig-version.cmake
OpenCVModules.cmake
OpenCVModules-release.cmake
-- Found OpenCV: Application/lib/opencv (found suitable version "4.4.0", minimum required is "4.2") 
-- Found Boost: Application/lib/boost/include (found suitable version "1.74.0", minimum required is "1.72")  
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:47 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" (requested
  version 4.2) with any of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Application/lib/SimulationLib/share/SimulationLibConfig.cmake:32 (find_dependency)
  CMakeLists.txt:159 (find_package)
```

edit: full cmakelists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12 FATAL_ERROR)

project(GameManagement_test
        VERSION 0.1
        LANGUAGES CXX
)

set(SOURCES
        "GameManagement_test.cpp"
)

enable_testing()

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

##########################################################################################
#boost linking
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180616/how-to-auto-link-boost-libraries-with-cmake

set( Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF )
set( Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON )
set( Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF )

if (WIN32)
    set( BOOST_ROOT "C:/local/boost_1_72_0" )
else()
    set( BOOST_ROOT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/boost/ )
    set( BOOST_INCLUDEDIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/boost/include )
    set( BOOST_LIBRARYDIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/boost/lib )
endif()

find_package( Boost 1.72 REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread fiber context )

if ( Boost_FOUND )
    include_directories( ${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR} )
    target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
else()
    message( FATAL_ERROR "Required Boost packages not found. Perhaps add -DBOOST_ROOT?" )
endif()

#boost linking end
##########################################################################################
##########################################################################################
#opencv linking

set( OpenCV_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib/opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4/")
find_package(OpenCV 4.2 REQUIRED)

if ( OpenCV_FOUND )
    target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
else()
    message( FATAL_ERROR "Required OpenCV packages not found." )
endif()

#opencv linking end
##########################################################################################

##########################################################################################
#SharedLib linking
set(SharedLib_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/SharedLib/share/")
find_package(SharedLib CONFIG )

if ( NOT SharedLib_FOUND )
    message("###############################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################")
    message("")
    message("Building SharedLib..")
    execute_process(COMMAND cmake 
                            -S ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../include/
                            -B ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../include/build/
                            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/SharedLib/
    )
    
    execute_process(COMMAND cmake --build ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../include/build/ --config Release --target install)
    message("Building SharedLib done")
    execute_process(COMMAND rm -R ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../include/build/)
    message("")
    message("###############################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################")
    
    set(SharedLib_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/SharedLib/share/")
    find_package(SharedLib CONFIG REQUIRED)
endif()

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} BallOnPlate::SharedLib)

#SharedLib linking end
##########################################################################################
##########################################################################################
#TrackingLib linking
set(TrackingLib_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/TrackingLib/share/")
set(TrackingLib_INCLUDE_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/TrackingLib/include" )
find_package(TrackingLib CONFIG )

if ( NOT TrackingLib_FOUND )
    message("###############################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################")
    message("")
    message("Building TrackingLib..")
    execute_process(COMMAND cmake 
                            -S ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Tracking/
                            -B ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Tracking/build/
                            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/TrackingLib/
    )
    execute_process(COMMAND cmake --build ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Tracking/build/ --config Release --target install
    )
    message("Building TrackingLib done")
    execute_process(COMMAND rm -R ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Tracking/build/)
    message("")
    message("###############################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################")
    
    set(TrackingLib_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/TrackingLib/share/")
    find_package(TrackingLib CONFIG REQUIRED)
endif()

include_directories( ${TrackingLib_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} BallOnPlate::TrackingLib)

#TrackingLib linking end
##########################################################################################
##########################################################################################
#PositioningLib linking
set(PositioningLib_DIR          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/PositioningLib/share/)
set(PositioningLib_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/PositioningLib/include)
find_package(PositioningLib CONFIG )

if ( NOT PositioningLib_FOUND )
    message("###############################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################")
    message("")
    message("Building PositioningLib..")
    execute_process(COMMAND cmake 
                            -S ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Positioning/
                            -B ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Positioning/build/
                            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/PositioningLib/
    )
    
    execute_process(COMMAND cmake --build ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Positioning/build/ --config Release --target install)
    message("Building PositioningLib done")
    execute_process(COMMAND rm -R ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Positioning/build/)
    message("")
    message("###############################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################")
    
    set(PositioningLib_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/PositioningLib/share/)
    find_package(PositioningLib CONFIG REQUIRED)
endif()

include_directories( ${PositioningLib_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} BallOnPlate::PositioningLib)

#PositioningLib linking end
##########################################################################################
##########################################################################################
#SimulationLib linking
set(SimulationLib_DIR           ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/SimulationLib/share/)
set(SimulationLib_INCLUDE_DIRS  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/SimulationLib/include)
find_package(SimulationLib CONFIG )

if ( NOT SimulationLib_FOUND )
    message("###############################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################")
    message("")
    message("Building SimulationLib..")
    execute_process(COMMAND cmake 
                            -S ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Simulation/
                            -B ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Simulation/build/
                            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/SimulationLib/
    )
    execute_process(COMMAND cmake --build ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Simulation/build/ --config Release --target install
    )
    message("Building SimulationLib done")
    execute_process(COMMAND rm -R ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Simulation/build/)
    message("")
    message("###############################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################")
    
    set(SimulationLib_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/SimulationLib/share/)
    find_package(SimulationLib CONFIG REQUIRED)
endif()

include_directories( ${SimulationLib_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} BallOnPlate::SimulationLib)

#SimulationLib linking end
##########################################################################################
##########################################################################################
#GameManagementLib linking
set(GameManagementLib_DIR           ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/GameManagementLib/share/)
set(GameManagementLib_INCLUDE_DIRS  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/GameManagementLib/include)
find_package(GameManagementLib CONFIG )

if ( NOT SimulationLib_FOUND )
    message("###############################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################")
    message("")
    message("Building GameManagementLib ...")
    execute_process(COMMAND cmake 
                            -S ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../GameManagement/
                            -B ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../GameManagement/build/
                            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/GameManagementLib/
    )
    execute_process(COMMAND cmake --build ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../GameManagement/build/ --config Release --target install
    )
    message("Building GameManagementLib done")
    execute_process(COMMAND rm -R ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../GameManagement/build/)
    message("")
    message("###############################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################")
    
    set(GameManagementLib_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/GameManagementLib/share/)
    find_package(GameManagementLib CONFIG REQUIRED)
endif()

include_directories( ${GameManagementLib_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} BallOnPlate::GameManagementLib)

#GameManagementLib linking end
##########################################################################################

##########################################################################################
#GTest linking

add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/gtest/" baaa)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} gtest gtest_main)

#GTest linking end
##########################################################################################

add_test(
    NAME {PROJECT_NAME}
    COMMAND {PROJECT_NAME}
)
```

Edit2:
Found the mistake, its within the cmake.in file.
I have it set to

```
set( OpenCV_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib/opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4/")
find_dependency(OpenCV 4.2 REQUIRED)
```

which works for the library the unit test is designed for, but as soon as the unit test has to be compiled this path does not work anymore and needs to be changed to

```
set( OpenCV_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib/opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4/")
```

just for the unit test. but how do fix this problem?

EDIT3:

```
set( OpenCV_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib/opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4/")
find_dependency(OpenCV 4.2 REQUIRED)
```

changed to

```
find_dependency(OpenCV 4.2 REQUIRED 
        HINTS 
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../lib/opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4/" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../lib/opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4/" 
)
```

which solved the problem

Comment: It seems you set `OpenCV_DIR` variable for help `find_package()` to find OpenCV. But on upper level the variable doesn't exist, so `find_package` has no longer a hint where to search OpenCV. You may make this variable a `CACHE` one, so it will be accessible even on upper level.

Comment: could you clarify that a bit?

Comment: `find_package(OpenCV)` uses `OpenCV_DIR` variable (if it is set) as a hint for OpenCV location. When called from `CMakeLists.txt` you show, `find_package(OpenCV)` sees that variable and checks a location specified by it. In the `CMakeLists.txt` from upper directory (you don't show this file, so we could only **guess** about its content) you also calls `find_package(OpenCV)`. But that time the variable `OpenCV_DIR` is not set. So `find_package(OpenCV)` fails to find the OpenCV package.

Comment: Ah, no you have misunderstood me.
this cmakelists is not called by another one(for now) . I it is executed by itself. I dont seem to have any errors if i remove one directory depth and adjust the open_cv variable accordingly.

Comment: Could you provide a code of the `CMakeLists.txt` which failed? Explanations are so ... vague.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes, its in the post

Comment: Ok, so problem was in `SimulationLibConfig.cmake` which redefined `OpenCV_DIR` to a wrong value.

Comment: Yes, ive just noticed that too. but i have honestly no clue how to fix this :/

Comment: Setting `OpenCV_DIR` variable inside `XXXConfig.cmake` looks unusual. But if you want to follow this way, you may compute the path relative to the `.cmake` itself using [CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html) variable. So you won't be dependent from the location of `CMakeLists.txt` which includes this `.cmake` file. Something like `set(OpenCV_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4/)`. (You may check correctness of the path's calculation using `message()` call inside this `.cmake` script).

Comment: I had the check since the start(first lines of the terminal dump), but unfortunetly using CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR did not change anything

Comment: Yes setting the OpenCV_DIR in the config is unusualy but since I have opencv build on another path than cmake checks i had to add it for the find_dependency module

Comment: Instead of `OpenCV_DIR` variable you may use `HINTS` option for the `find_dependency` macro. So your `.cmake` script won't redefine setting of `OpenCV_DIR` variable in the main project. As for `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` variable, it won't help only if **relative location** of `OpenCVConfig.cmake` and `SimulationLibConfig.cmake` **differs** between the cases when you perform testing and when you use the `SimulationLib` normally. Please, add more information about that difference into the question post.

Comment: THANK YOU. HINTS was the solution.